# background header changes size when switch page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why my background grows bigger when switching from one page to the next. They style is perfect one the home page. But when I switch to the portfolio or the contact page seems to me it adds padding to it.

```css
header {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

header ul {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <!--site title-->
      <h1>
        Clayton J. Batchelor
      </h1>

        <!--Navigation section-->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="portfolio.html">
              Portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </header>
```

Comment: Does the code you've posted here reproduce the problem? Can you point out what you mean specifically by "the background growing bigger"? You might try removing `display: inline-block;` from `header`, and adding `overflow: auto;`

Comment: inspect the empty space and see where is the source, then remove it from css.

Comment: the problem was when i viewed it from atom using right click open to browser it had that effect. But when i uploaded it to github it stayed they same. So there must be a small bug in one of the programs. thanks for your help. you can see it on https://cltnbatchelor.github.io/portfolio/index.html